# Focus on installer of extracted file after download in Chrome on OS X Lion

Tags: macos, google-chrome, window-focus

When I download something in OS X, say an installer or zip file, from Chrome and I click it, it doesn't get focus. So I have go to Mission Control and find where it is. Any way to get focus automatically on clicked installers?

Answer (score 1):

If you download a disk image file (`.dmg`) and click it, it will be mounted and opened in the Finder. Therefore, just `Cmd-Tab` to the Finder to see it.

Click the downloaded file …

[image: Chrome status bar]

… `Cmd-Tab` to Finder, and see:

[image: finder]

---

If you download a `.zip` file, or anything else that's opened by `BOMArchiveHelper`, it will most likely be extracted into your Downloads folder. Normally, that's something run in the background.

If you use a program like [The Unarchiver](http://wakaba.c3.cx/s/apps/unarchiver.html), you can configure it to automatically show extracted files.

[image]

This way, when you click an archive downloaded through Chrome, it'll automatically show in Finder.